# Objective C method syntax clarification

Tags: objective-c, syntax, methods

I'm new to Objective C and I'm going through [a tutorial I found online](http://objc.toodarkpark.net/coreobjc.html#1296). The tutorial starts to talk about messaging and argument separation and gives an example:

> When there's more than one argument, they're declared within the method name after the colons. Arguments break the name apart in the declaration, just as in a message.
>
> ```
> - (void)setWidth:(float)width: height:(float)height;
> ```

I don't think there is suppose to be a colon after width, but I could be wrong. From what I've researched, I believe that it's a typo, but since I am new I just wanted to check.

Is the method just `setWidth: height:`  ? Or is there another argument after the `(float)width` other than `height:(float)height`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo. The method signature should read:

`- (void)setWidth:(float)width height:(float)height;`

The method name is `setWidth:height:` and you would call it like this:

`[someObject setWidth:aFloat height:anotherFloat];`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The middle colon seems to be a typo. After a colon, there should be a variable placeholder.  If there's a space after a colon (as in this case) it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you would be correct. That is a typo. You would call that method like so:

```
[obj setWidth:100.0f height:200.0f];
```

Referencing that method in documentation or for a method callback it should be labeled setWidth:height: (note the trailing colon). Good luck with the rest of the tutorial.